# Can someone provide assistance with Javascript code to validate a custom field on a web to lead form?

Tags: javascript, web2lead, developer

I have a basic web to lead form. I have created the following javascript code to ensure that a couple of my standard fields are filled in. If they are left blank the javascript error appears, and alerts the person filling out the form. The issue I am running into is the last field I want to validate that it is not left blank, is a custom picklist. The field has an ID rather than a text name, so it's not working with the javascript code I used for the other fields.

Here is the code that works:

```
function validation(form) {


if(form.first_name.value == '') {

alert('Please enter your first name');
form.first_name.focus();
return false;
}


if(form.last_name.value == '') {

alert('Please enter your last name');
form.last_name.focus();
return false;
}

if(form.email.value == '') {

alert('Please enter your email address');
form.email.focus();
return false;
}



return true;
}
```

Any assistance or direction on how to proceed is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Within SFDC, one uses the TEXT() function to transform picklist values into text for evaluation. Is there a similar JS function to convert your picklist values to text so that your == '' test could evaluate them?